# KDB+ Case insensitive like query

Tags: java, database, kdb

```
SELECT * FROM MarketTable WHERE customer LIKE "ABC"
```

This returns only ABC.  I want this to return ABC, aBC, abc, etc.

Is there something close to `ILIKE` in kDB+?

Even functions like `lower` or `tolowercase` would help, but I do not think these are available.  As in java we have `string.tolowercase`.

Answer (score 4):

```
q)t:([] b:1 2 3; a:("abC";"aBc";"AbC"))
q)t
b a
-------
1 "abC"
2 "aBc"
3 "AbC"

q)select from t where upper[a] like "ABC"
b a
-------
1 "abC"
2 "aBc"
3 "AbC"

q)select from t where lower[a] like "abc"
b a
-------
1 "abC"
2 "aBc"
3 "AbC"
```

However this way the conversion has to happen on each query. Faster to store the column in the format that it will be queried.

Answer (score 2):

another approach could be below. This should be faster but please check on your data

```
test: ([] id: (1; 2; 3; 4; 5); customer: ("abc"; "ABC"; "Abc"; "aBC"; "ABB"))
select from test where raze max customer like/: all_casings["abc"]
all_casings: {
fstr: 1#x;
ans: $[(count[x])>1;(upper[fstr],/: all_casings[1_x]), lower[fstr],/: all_casings[1_x];     ((upper[x]); lower[x])];
ans
};
```

Comment: why the downvote? Wouldn't it make more sense to apply any functions to a smaller input argument rather than the whole data